# CMS options for integrating with a separate backend?

Tags: node.js, content-management-system

Our site relies heavily on content,  so it is important that we have a CMS which allows authors to publish easily. On the other hand, we need to perform some operations (price comparisons, running webhooks, providing a webservice) in the backend which should be decoupled from the content management logic and we would want them to be separated from the CMS, so developers can forget about templating, etc, and focus on the heavy stuff. I was thinking on having a nodeJS backend app + a PHP CMS. The CMS should interact with the backend via a REST API using json, so content managers upload their stuff easily, important information is saved in the backend for us to work with via the API and both developers and content managers are happy.
What CMS would allow for an integration like this?

Answer (score -2):

This is popular direction with the Content Management Systems.  Lots of possible searches: Headless CMS, Decoupled CMS, API-First CMS, Content as a Service (CaaS)

I'd recommend taking a look at Cloud CMS.

Cloud CMS provides a really solid API oriented entirely around JSON and binary attachments. It runs on top of MongoDB and ElasticSearch to offer structured query and full-text search for all of your content. It also includes a very powerful dictionary system to let you model out your content types, graph associations and aspect-oriented features.

It's entirely JSON Schema in it's orientation and really flexible. Furthermore, you can access Cloud CMS in the public cloud or you can run your own on-premise / virtual private cloud instances using Docker.

We also provide a fully integrated forms engine for auto-generation of role-based, content entry forms. Our application server is built on Node.js and we've open-sourced this along with our forms engine (https://www.alpacajs.org) and all of our drivers.

Disclaimer: I am an employee of the company.